# Trigger cast operator on use of the dot operator

Tags: c++, casting, implicit-conversion

I have a class something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
    operator const T & () const
    {
        return value;
    }
private:
    T value;
};
```

I then use it with a struct like this:

```
struct point { float x; float y; };

//...

wrapper<point> myPoint;
std::cout << myPoint.x;// error: no member x or whatever.
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to allow this without having to do ((point)myPoint).x. I know that I can overload the -> operator but I'd prefer not to since its supposed to "pretend" to be a non-pointer.

Comment: You can say `static_cast<point const &>(myPoint).x`.

Comment: You could change the cast operator to `operator()` and use `myPoint().x;` if the length is what you're trying to avoid. It makes less sense than `operator->`, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something *similar* with `->` instead of `.`:

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
    operator const T & () const // will this still be needed now?
    {
        return value;
    }

    T* operator->() { return &value; }
    T const* operator->() const { return &value; }

private:
    T value;
};
```

And then:

```
struct point { float x; float y; }

//...

wrapper<point> myPoint; // this needs to be initialised!
std::cout << myPoint->x;
```

Comment: @Mr.Anubis oh yes, you're right. That was copied straight from the question.

Comment: This is nice and all, but would it not make more sense to have a .GetValue() operator?

Comment: @JohanLundberg How could I know which makes more sense? I don't know what a `wrapper` is supposed to be.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: The problem is that you cannot do this with `.`. Among the alternatives, `operator->` is the one that probably makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make your wrapper class pretend to be a real class the way you described.  The main reason is that member selection (.) operator cannot be overloaded.

Comment: Kinda surprised this had no votes. It's brief, but the answer is that simple... _currently_. There's an ongoing push for `operator.` https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup As well as handling explicit accesses by `.`, this is proposed to hijack _all_ accesses (e.g. `operator=`) not defined in the class & forward those to the result of `operator.` I worry this implicit role seems too broad, risky, out of scope relative to its name, & lazy: if you want to forward operators, write them... But Bjarne is one of the proposals' authors, so!